# Asp.net MVC entity framework Path is not working in - WebAPI Controller Class

Tags: entity-framework

### Filename: DemoController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MVCEntityFramework.Controllers.Api
{
    public class DemoController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

ScreenShot 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDQ4O.png
ScreenShot 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObG6W.png

Path Not Working:

1. https://localhost:44310/api/demo/get/2
2. https://localhost:44310/api/democontroller/get/2

Response:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

It'll work by convention so if you need to call Get by id just use https://localhost:44310/api/demo/2 without action name but you need to specify verb HttpGet if you need to call Post also you will call https://localhost:44310/api/demo with specify verb HttpPost
This is how to call post action using postman for example

[image]

or add [Route("[controller]")] attribute to class like

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DemoController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    [Route("Get")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

so in this case you can add controller name to your endpoint like https://localhost:44310/api/demo/get/2

Comment: [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DemoController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
  
  URL: https://localhost:44310/api/demo/get/2
  
  Response: 
  HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
  The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: answer updated add route attribute to each action